# How to visualize an image segment borders in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation, vlfeat

I have a matrix with segment indices for each pixel of image. How can I visualize the borders of the segments? The most obvious idea is to use diff filter to obtain the edge map, but it looks very ugly. How can I make the image look like here?
http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/slic.html

UPD: I've tried this and it looks OK. The code itself looks ugly, perhaps it can be written in a more elegant form.

```
boundaries = zeros(size(segments));
boundaries(2:end, :) = boundaries(2:end, :) + (segments(2:end, :) ~= segments(1:end-1, :));
boundaries(:, 2:end) = boundaries(:, 2:end) + (segments(:, 2:end) ~= segments(:, 1:end-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the places of the indices (for example a binary mask of where the borders are), you can use `imoverlay` to do that.

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10502-image-overlay

For something faster, especially if you only need one colour, why don't you just do something like

(assuming the borders are stored in a logical array: `borders` and you image in `img`)

```
img(borders) = 0
```

to make all the pixels in the `borders` mask black

Comment: I don't have the borders array, the question is how to create it.